# Is it possible to run CrystalDiskInfo from the command line/powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, powershell, crystaldiskinfo

I want to be able to run CrystalDiskInfo from the cmd to save and analyze the data. I want to do it in a way where I can automatically run CrystalDiskInfo on a remote device and send commands based on the data output. Also, I want to do it in a way that it won't be intrusive to someone who is also using the computer a the same time. (AKA CrystalDiskInfo won't just open up randomly and start running, or that the window is hidden from the user).
I know there are these:

Command Line Option
/Exit : Auto exit after updating S.M.A.R.T. information and AAM/APM status

/Copy :

Output “Edit > Copy” result to DiskInfo.txt

/CopyExit :

Output “Edit > Copy” result to DiskInfo.txt and auto exit

but I have no idea how to use them.

Comment: `/CopyExit` is the option to use. You would need to analyze the `DiskInfo.txt` text file for the status.

Comment: I don't see it. Where is it?

Comment: I don't use this app. Look in the current folder or search the entire disk

Comment: Why not just use [`smartctl`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage) directly?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone finds this useful. I made a powershell script to parse some of this info for my own use:

```
$cdiskinfo="C:\Program Files\CrystalDiskInfo"
& "$cdiskinfo\DiskInfo64.exe" /CopyExit
$s=gc "$cdiskinfo\DiskInfo.txt"
$models=($s | select-string "           Model : ") -replace "           Model : ",""
$firmwares=($s | select-string "        Firmware : ") -replace "        Firmware : ",""
$healths=($s | Select-String "   Health Status : ") -replace "   Health Status : ",""
$dletters=($s | Select-String "    Drive Letter : ") -replace "    Drive Letter : ",""
$temps=($s | Select-String "     Temperature : ") -replace "     Temperature : ",""
$feats=($s | Select-String "        Features : ") -replace "        Features : ",""
$Drives=`
for ($i=0;$i -lt $models.count;$i++) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{"Model"=$models[$i];"Firmware"=$firmwares[$i];"Health"=$healths[$i];"Letter"=$dletters[$i];"Temp"=$temps[$i];"Features"=$feats[$i]}
}
$Drives
```

Comment: Hello, a better formatting and/or some comments would be good for script's readability.